# Python - Convert RGB picture to Gray Manually

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library, grayscale

I want to convert an rgb image to 2d matrix in gray. How can I do this using loops and PIL? I don't want to use a canned function. How can I do that ?

Comment: you need loop and use https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/PixelAccess.html to change every pixel (for example r = 30, g= 40 b= 20 do they all = 30 (by red channel)

Answer (score 0):

I manipulate a lot of images as NumPy arrays like so:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Load image
imgIn = Image.open(''c:/path/to/my/input/file.jpg'')
imgArray = np.array(imgIn)

#Do whatever manipulations to the image you need to, e.g.,
grayArray = np.mean(imgArray,axis=2)

#Save the final result
imgOut = Image.fromarray(grayArray)
imgOut.save('c:/path/to/my/output/file.jpg')
```